# Couldn't perform the edit because another user changed the record

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Alguém sabe se fica algum vestígio de uma tabela que é dropada de um banco? Para facilitar caso ela seja recriada, por exemplo, e quando digo vestígio é nas entranhas do banco mesmo.

Estou passando por aquele famoso problema do 'Couldn't perform the edit because another user changed the record.' em uma conexão do SQL com o BDE/Delphi, da parte de programação no Delphi já foi feito tudo para evitar o problema.

Agora, se crio uma nova tabela com outro nome, mas com a mesma estrutura e com os dados da tabela que tem o campo que apresenta o erro, que no caso é um *FLOAT*, a tabela nova não apresenta o erro.

Seguindo esse processo, se excluo a tabela que apresentava o erro, e recrio ela com mesmo nome pegando a estrutura da tabela nova que havia criado e repassando os dados também dessa tabela, o erro volta a acontecer.

Ou seja, o problema só acontece quando crio a tabela com o nome em que o erro foi apresentado a primeira vez. A única suspeita que me restou foi a de que o banco guarda alguma informação sobre a tabela que foi dropada, e quando é recriada, ele edita seus dados de alguma forma, o que faz apresentar o erro.

Comment: Porque você precisa recriar a tabela? O Post deveria funcionar sem gerar nenhum erro. Como está esse campo no banco e como o Delphi mapeou ele?

Comment: Você tentou mudar o updateMode para upWhereKeyOnly? Isso deveria resolver o problema sem a necessidade de recriar a tabela

Comment: Tentou mudar de RequestLive para CachedUpdates? Além de aumentar a performance, também poderia resolver o problema.

Comment: Quando você diz que tudo foi feito em Delphi para garantir o funcionamento você quer dizer que essas duas alterações já foram feitas?

Comment: Exato, faz tempo que estou com o problema, e para casos novos, fiz as mesmas alterações que citou no Delphi e parou de acontecer o problema. Mas para os casos que apresentaram o problema antes das alterações no Delphi, mesmo que passe a usar a versão corrigida, o problema continua acontecendo.

Comment: O campo é FLOAT no banco, e mesmo sem instanciar usando SELECT * ou instanciando como FLOAT no Delphi acontece o problema. Parti para a recriação da tabela pois vi que se criasse uma nova com a mesma estrutura, mas com outro nome, o problema não acontecia.

Comment: Não entendi, o que são novos casos e o que são casos antes das alterações?

Comment: É viagem minha, o problema agora, depois que fiz as alterações no delphi, se criar uma tabela nova e gravar um campo float com uma dízima maior que 15 dígitos não acontece o erro, se usar uma tabela antiga, mesmo dropando ela, e recriando, o erro acontece.

Comment: @RobsonBraz, o que é tudo que você fez para evitar o problema? Pois com essa afirmação você pode induzir os colegas e a si mesmo a nunca encontrar o erro, uma vez que o problema ainda pode esta sendo gerado por um erro de programação, quando usamos BDE para acessar arquivos é normal que esses fiquem corrompidos, já tentou reinstalar o BDE?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o problema é com a BDE mesmo. Não com o banco de dados.

Se a resposta fosse apenas a respeito da BDE, a minha recomendação seria na verdade abandonar a BDE e partir para um *provider* de mapeamento de dados menos problemático, como o [FreeDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/freedac/), por exemplo. Ou, ainda, para [SDAC](https://www.devart.com/sdac/) (pago), ou ainda ADO (já vem com o Delphi), se você tiver paciência pra adaptar o código e ordenar os parâmetros na ordem em que eles aparecem.

Passada essa pequena recomendação, vamos à resposta.

Esse problema ocorre com algumas coisas. De modo geral, para resolver, faça o seguinte, suponho uma estrutura com um `TDataSetProvider` e um `TClientDataset`:

```
DatasetProvider.UpdateMode = upWhereKeyOnly;
ClientDataSet.ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate];
```

No campo chave do `TClientDataSet` defina as `ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]`.

Retire também as `ProviderFlags` de todos os outros campos.

Comment: Já fiz estas alterações no Delphi, e não posso deixar de usar o BDE, o sistema é muito grande. O problema agora creio que seja no banco sim, pois se criar uma tabela nova e gravar um campo float com uma dízima maior que 15 dígitos não acontece o erro, se usar uma tabela antiga, mesmo dropando ela, e recriando, o erro acontece.

Comment: @RobsonBraz O SDAC tem um migrador de tecnologia. Você não precisa fazer nada: apenas executar o migrador que ele troca todas as referências dos objetos da BDE pra você. Nos meus sistemas, pra evitar este tipo de problema, eu usava BCD ao invés de Float.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez BCD não suporta mais do que 4 casas.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound É verdade, mas não sei se a aplicação dele é mais direcionada para o científico ou para o financeiro. Para este último, BCD é melhor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Concordo

Comment: @RobsonBraz Quem deve estar cacheando alguma coisa deve ser o BDE, o banco não é o culpado aqui.

Comment: @RobsonBraz Faça uma view para essa sua tabela, com outro nome e faça os testes com a view para ver se funciona ou não.